# Recuperar archivo especifico mediante tar

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

He creado en una carpeta "datos" un archivo llamado "yonaguni" y he creado una copia .tar del directorio "home", ¿Cómo puedo recuperar solamente el archivo "yonaguni" sin que se recuperen a su vez todo lo almacenado en la copia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5):

Tienes que ponerlo de este modo:

```
tar -xvf datos.tar ruta/del/archivo/yonaguni
```

donde los parámetros con guión son:

- **x**: de eXtract (extraer)
- **v**: de Verbose (mostrar información durante la operación)
- **f**: Define que el archivo comprimido es de tipo File (del sistema de archivos, en lugar de por ejemplo, cinta o TAPE).

Esa instrucción te extrae solo el archivo que coincida con esa ruta y nombre de archivo, por lo tanto debes saberlo previamente.

Para averiguar la ruta del archivo "yonaguni" puedes probar con esto:

```
tar -t datos.tar | grep "yonaguni"
```

y deberia mostrartela para que luego la puedas aplicar en la primera instrucción de esta respuesta.